# check if key exist in object

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, json

I am trying to check if key ("Gen") exists and if exists return the value itself if not return "Unknown".

my object looks like this.

```
study = {
  "005": 
     {

        "Gen" : ["F"],
        "vr" : "cs"
      }
}
study = {
  "005": 
      {
        "vr" : "cs"
      }
}
```

in function i am trying to return the value of "Gen"

```
var gen = study["005"].Gen !== "undefined" || study["005"].Gen !== null ? study["005"].Gen[0] : "Unknown";
```

but here it throws me an error as in second case : where "Gen" doesn't exist but still it passes the if condition and looks for study["005"].Gen[0]

how to check if the "Gen" exists!!
Any help appreciated.

Comment: It is invalid data. Either `"005"` is an array that contains objects or an object that contains `Gen` and `vr` properties.

Comment: Check for `undefined` rather than the string `”undefined”`.

Comment: If Gen does not exist then the condition `study["005"].Gen !== null` becomes true and hence it's passes the if condition.

Comment: yes, i by mistake added an extra curly brackets in json value. (corrected it in question).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Standard function style here for your reference. You should use `.hasOwnProperty`

```
study = {
  "005": {     
        "Gen" : ["F"],
        "vr" : "cs"      
   },
}
let gen;
function check() {
  if (study["005"].hasOwnProperty("Gen")) {
    gen = study["005"]["Gen"]
  } else
    gen = "Unknown"
}
check()
console.log(gen)
```

And what you want

```
var gen = study["005"].hasOwnProperty("Gen") ? study["005"]["Gen"] : "Unknown" ;
```

Comment: it works :) thank you..mistake i did was : checking the condition itself and then accessing the value of "Gen".

Answer (score 3):

You can use the nullish coalescing operator:

```
var gen = study["005"].Gen ?? "Unknown";
```

Comment: Alternatively: `Object.keys(study['005']).includes('Gen') ? study['005']['Gen'] : 'Unknown';`

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to change it to

```
var gen = study["005"].Gen !== undefined ? study["005"].Gen[0] : "Unknown" ;
```

Additionally, you have an extra pair of curly brackets. Instead of

```
study = {
  "005": {
      {
        "Gen" : ["F"],
        "vr" : "cs"
      }
   },
}
study = {
  "005": {
      {
        "vr" : "cs"
      }
   }
}
```

it should be

```
study = {
  "005": {
      "Gen" : ["F"],
      "vr" : "cs"
   },
}
study = {
  "005": {
      "vr" : "cs"
   },
}
```

Comment: yes you are right..i had by mistake added extra pair of curly brackets.. but corrected it now. meanwhile i tried the code which you said but i get the error in console.. var gen = study["005"].Gen !== undefined ? study["005"].Gen[0] : "Unknown" ; Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

The correct condition to check for the key will be:
`study["005"].Gen !== undefined && study["005"].Gen !== null ? study["005"].Gen[0] : "Unknown";`

Answer (score 0):

I think the data is invalid as well, so I tried cleaning it up a little. Does the following work for you?

```js
const study = {
    "005":
    {
        "Gen": ["F"], "vr": "cs"
    }

}

if(JSON.stringify(study['005']).includes('Gen')) {
    console.log(study['005']['Gen']);
}
```